# Vertical Linear Imageview goes at the bottom

Tags: android, xml, widget

i am working on a layout with 3 buttons and an image view i call the imageview as the first child of the parent however when i build it on actual device the imageview goes down after the buttons... really weird....

heres the xml file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/title_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/111"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/222"
            android:visibility="visible"
           />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/highscores_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/highscore_btn"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/more_apps_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_medium"
                    android:background="@drawable/333"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

is this because of the size of the imageview? it is really large so i put it in xxhdpi folder so it will be reduced. any thoughts? thanks

Comment: So basically what type of ui you need?

Comment: You could have just used a linear layout with orientation=verticle and use your image then the buttons in that order ,Why you use a frame layout

Comment: i need the frame layout for another purpose.. i dont think the frame layout affects the widgets since i put them on a linearlayout parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/title_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/111"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/222"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/highscores_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/highscore_btn"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/more_apps_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:background="@drawable/333"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: it goes on top but it fills the whole screen...~

Comment: i have deleted the weight and put wrap_content in the layout_height and now it works fine... have any ideas why this occur? please update your answer as i have accepted it.